# Data Definition Language (DDL) Statements Logging / Retrieval

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
 SELECT name, 
    TYPE, 
    type_desc, 
    create_date, 
    modify_date 
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE TYPE IN ('U','V','PK','F','D','P') 
    AND modify_date >= Dateadd(HOUR,21,Cast((Cast(Getdate() - 4 AS VARCHAR(12))) AS SMALLDATETIME)) 
    ORDER BY modify_date
```

I'm using the above query to try and get what data definition statements were made in the database and on what date and time.

How can i also get exactly what DDL statement was executed for each row returned?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see the detailed information, you have to set up some kind of auditing first -- either using DDL trgiggers or SQL Server Audit feature (were auditing available in 2005 at all? think not).

Check the default trace:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/